# while loop passing different values but ajax will get first value only

Tags: php, ajax, phpmyadmin

i am using php ajax to pass and get the result but javascript will take only first loop value

Here my code:

```
<?php     
      $sql = 'SELECT * from booking_master
      INNER JOIN   *****
      WHERE booking_master.user_id=:id';

      $query = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $query->bindParam(':id', $id);

      $query->execute();

      if($query->rowCount())
      {

           while($row11 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
           {

  ?> 
  <tr>
          <td> <?php echo $row11['user_name']; ?> </td> 
          <input type="hidden" name="userid" id="userid" value="<?php echo $row11['user_id']; ?>">
          <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row11['plot_id']; ?>"  name="plotid" id="plotid">

          <td> <?php echo $row11['auto-book-id'];?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $row11['plot_id'];?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $row11['plot_name'];?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $row11['trans_date'];?></td>


          <td> <a href="#"  onclick="functscheme()" > Select Plot</a>

 </tr>
 <?php 
           }
      } 
 ?>
```

ajax code:

```
 function functscheme()
 {
     var userid=document.getElementById('userid').value;
     var plotid=document.getElementById('plotid').value;

     alert(plotid);
```

but in that plot it returns only first value

Comment: *id's* are meant to be unique identifiers, and thus will only return the first instance that it finds. You will ned non-unique identifiers, such as *name* and *class* attributes if you wish to make use of multiple *"hits"*.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` only returns the first element with that ID (because IDs are only intended to be used on one element). Try using classes instead.

In PHP:

```
<!-- These have the "class" attribute instead of "id" now -->
<input type="hidden" name="userid" class="userid" value="<?php echo $row11['user_id']; ?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $row11['plot_id']; ?>"  name="plotid" class="plotid">
```

In JS:

```
// Get lists of HTML elements for inputs
// (selected by class)
var userIDElements = document.getElementsByClassName('userid');
var plotIDElements = document.getElementsByClassName('plotid');

// Array.from() converts the HTMLCollection to a normal JS Array
//   (this is necessary so we can use .map)
// .map(func) runs func on each element of the array, and returns a new
//  array with the results of that
// e.g. here, the function takes each <input> element found, and returns
//  its value, so now we have a list of values rather than a list of elements
var userIDs = Array.from(userIDElements).map(function (element) { return element.value; });
var plotIDs = Array.from(plotIDElements).map(function (element) { return element.value; });
```

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for more details about `.map()`.

**Edit:** The code I had put before was wrong - sorry.

Comment: It is not working can i know the meaning of    .map(el => el.value) & where u r calling that variable..?   #Smith

Comment: @Darshan Sorry, the code was wrong before - I think it should work now. I've also added some comments explaining it, and a link to more information about .map().